# Creating and re-selecting SObject has different results

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, date

I have this simple bit of unit test code as below.
It uses a Job_History__c custom object which has a master-detail relationship to another custom object, Employment__c.

The Employment__c object has custom fields Start_Date__c and End_date__c which, as their names suggest, are Date type.

The Job_History__c object has a custom field Effective_Date__c, also a Date type.

The method under test, `validateJH(Job_History__c)`, should return false if `Job_History__c.Effective_Date__c` is outside the range of `Employment__c.Start_Date__c` to `Employment__c.End_Date__c`.

Note that `Employment__c.End_Date__c` may by null, in which case `validateJH(Job_History__c)` will return false if `Job_History__c.Effective_Date__c` is before `Employment__c.Start_Date__c`.

```
 @isTest
 public static void testValidateJHEmpPast(){          
     Employment__c pastEmp = new Employment__c();
     pastEmp.Start_Date__c = System.today().addMonths(-1);
     pastEmp.End_Date__c =null;
     insert pastEmp;

     Job_History__c jobH1 = new Job_History__c();
     jobH1.Effective_Date__c = System.today();
     jobH1.Employment__c = pastEmp.Id;
     insert jobH1;

     Job_History__c jh2 = [select Employment__r.Start_Date__c, Employment__r.End_Date__c, Effective_Date__c from Job_History__c where Id=:jobH1.id];

     System.assert(validateJH(jh2) == true);          
  }
```

This test only passes if I reselect the `Job_History__c` I've just created, as in the code above. If I pass in the original one I inserted (`jobH1`), the test fails because Employment__c.Start_Date__c is null for some reason.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

On the jobH1 you just set the Employee__c for that object. After that you are performing a DML operation **insert**.

- Inorder to derive the data from related object Employee__c you need to perform one more SOQL as you have did.
- Object just holds data of that particular context, in this context it holds only Employee__c and not all the related fields of it
- Once you perform any DML database gets updated, but not the object which you used for DML. So you need to explicitly query back to get the latest data

**Ref**: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BUYdIAO